# how to initilaize member variables from the primary constructor

Tags: android, class, kotlin, constructor

I am new to Kotlin development. I was trying to create a simple example to know the primary and secondary constructors, so I referred to the below-posted link.
however, the class created below seems to have a bug despite I copied from [this link](https://blog.mindorks.com/primary-and-secondary-constructors-in-kotlin)

please let me know how should I amend the below-posted class so I can have the code running.

**MainActivity**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val LOG_TAG : String = "MainActivity"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var p1 = CustomPerson("Ar", "Agi", 25632909)
    //nonScopingFunc1(p1)

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "p1: " + p1.address)

}

/*private func nonScopingFunc1 (p:CustomPerson) : CustomPerson {
    var person : Person = getPersonName(p)
    var person : Person = getPersonAddress(p)
    var person : Person = getPersonPhone(p)
}*/
}
```

**customClass**

```
 class CustomPerson (_name: String, _address: String, _phoneNum: Long) {

var name: String
var address: String
var phoneNum: Long

 init {
     println("Initialized a new Person object with name = $name , address = $address and phoneNum = $phoneNum")
 }
}
```

Comment: what's the current issue

Comment: You are missing some lines in the `init` of `CustomPerson` see the link again and try to add the missing lines ...

Comment: Looking at the quality of the linked page, I can only advise you not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss some lines to copy from the link:

```
class Person(_name: String, _age: Int, _salary: Int) {
    // Member Variables (Properties) of the class
    var name: String
    var age: Int 
    var salary: Int 

    // Initializer Block
    init {
        this.name = _name
        this.age = _age 
        this.salary = _salary 
       println("Initialized a new Person object with Name = $name , age = $age and salary = $salary")
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to replace the init() block with and use the secondary constructor instead..would you please let how to use it ..as i recived errors regarding using var or val on the 2nd constructor

Answer (score 0):

not need shadow variable

```
 class CustomPerson (private val name: String,private val address: String, private val phoneNum: Long) {

 init {
       println("Initialized a new Person object with name = $name , address = 
       $address and phoneNum = $phoneNum")
  }
 }
```